# Remove css files from ajax calling data in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I built a module in drupal 7 with ajax support.But now i am in a big trouble, when i am calling the ajax for certain data fetching at that moment due to inclusion of system.menu.css file with the fetched data my website css breaks.

So could you please guide me how can i remove those unnecessary files from ajax fetched data, mainly the css and js files in Drupal 7.

Comment: how do you exactly call the fetched content ?

Comment: through ajax calling like ajax_delivery();

Comment: how is the url bound to the menu ? (show some code pls)

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem with a site I was working on. It appears in the theme .info file someone had added these two entries:

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/drupal/system.theme.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/drupal/system.menus.css
```

I removed them, cleared the theme registry, and the problem went away.